# how to parse a json similar string and map it into a pojo

Tags: json, parsing, mapping, pojo, jackson-databind

I am trying to map the following JSON to my POJO using Jackson. I have the following JSON and following POJOs. kindly let me know how to map the JSON to POJO.
JSON string :

```
{
  "Application": {
    "id": "0",
    "name": "MyApp",
    "users": [
      {
        "User": {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Beth Jones"
        }
      }
    ],
    "groups": [
      {
        "Group": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "SimpleGroup",
          "users": [
            {
              "User": {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Beth Jones"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The POJO according to the client specification is below :

```
package com.example.custom;

//import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.example.Application;
import com.example.Group;
import com.example.User;

import java.util.Collection;

//@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Collection<User> users;

    private Collection<Group> groups;

    public MyApplication(String id, String name) {

        super(id, name);
    }

    public void setUsers(Collection<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public void setGroups(Collection<Group> groups) {

        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<User> getUsers() {

        return this.users;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String userId) {

        for (User user: MyParser.myApp.getUsers()) {
            if (user.getId().equals(userId))
                return user;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Group> getGroups() {

        return this.groups;
    }

    @Override
    public Group getGroup(String groupId) {

        for (Group group: MyParser.myApp.getGroups()) {
            if (group.getId().equals(groupId))
                return group;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyApplication{" +
                "users=" + users +
                ", groups=" + groups +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Mapping Logic :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
MyParser.myApp = mapper.readValue(rewriter.getText(),MyApplication.class);
```

The resulting object is not able to capture anything as it is all null. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should model your JSON correctly, In the `users` list you shouldn't specify it again that the key is **User**, that should be preassumed that a list of users will only contain user, same goes for `groups` list.

IMHO the JSON should look something like this :

```
{
  "application": {
    "id": "0",
    "name": "MyApp",
    "users": [ . ==> Since this is a user List, it will definitely contains user.
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Beth Jones"
      }
    ],
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "SimpleGroup",
        "users": [
          {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Beth Jones"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now the POJO also needs some modification, I am just adding the bare-minimum POJO.

```
class Application {  <====== Top Level Class
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<User> users;  // Application has some Users
    private List<Group> groups; // Application has some groups
}

class User {   
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

class Group {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<User> users;  // Each group has some associated users.
}
```

Now you can use any standard JSON library for Java and convert your JSON into POJO. This will simplify your structure and you won't face null issues with this structure.

Comment: Thank you @Neeraj, I will give it a try. Let me also know how to parse a JSON like structure without using any library.

Comment: Why you don't want to use any library, they are exposed as a library for a purpose, there is no need to reinvent the wheel which the community has tested well for ages.

Comment: ...I actually want to understand what are the different ways to implement it. Most of the time, coding assignments for jobs don't allow to use existing libraries. Though I can take a look at the source code of these libraries, request you to provide any pointer /approach on the same if possible.